# What does this sentence mean? "Lisp has attracted some of the brightest minds in the history of computer science."

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

folks.
I would like to get your help.
Please accept me as your obedient student.

I wonder what the sentence mean.
Below is the sentence which is from a computer programming book about programming language LISP.

"Lisp has attracted some of the brightest minds in the history of computer science."

Does "brightest minds" mean some good programmers?
Does that sentence mean that Lisp succeeded to attract attentions from some, famous, good computer programmers?

Any explanations will be appreciated greatly. Thanks.

Comment: This should be a good clue: **[mind](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/mind_1)**: 2a. [countable] someone who is very intelligent.

Comment: Yes, you understand it all right. Because the *genre* is programming. I, as a doctor, though brilliant, won't get attracted anyhow.

Comment: There is a difference between Computer Science and computer programming. Computer Science deals with the theory of computing and can be very mathematical in nature. Computer programming is about writing computer software (for example programmers [or software-engineers] created Microsoft Word). The topics aren't mutually exclusive but you can make a similar comparison between scientists and engineers in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bright:

> *adjective*, intelligent and quick-witted.

Mind:

> *noun*, a person identified with their intellectual faculties

So 'brightest minds in the history of computer science' simply means the most intelligent people in the field of computer science.

Comment: One point that could be interesting for the OP: do you think it's necessary that these brightest minds had to be in the field of computer science before Lisp attracted them?